# Github actions can not run the config.sh file in the ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, github-actions

I am trying to set up the GitHub actions in ubuntu. I made a folder and install the runner using my root account. Now, this is how permissions look like.

[image]

When I tried to run
`sudo ./config.sh --url https://github.com/user/api --token supersecret`

It gives me the error

> Must not run with sudo

The solution most people say is that `export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"` and then run the command. But this widely accepted solution is not working for me for some reason.

And some others say create a non-root user and try to run. I tried that way too. It ends up with more errors.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which errors show up when you create a new user? Edit: Also, there seems to have been a user with user id 101 and group id 212 before. What has happened to them?

Comment: Do what the error message says and run without `sudo`. Focus on the errors you get when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way to run env `❯ sudo env RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1" ./run.sh`

for the config just keep the same pattern, put the `env` at the beginning.